# How does docker work with images of different architectures?

Tags: docker, repository, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I'm making cross-architecture images using docker build, and docker buildx. I'm wondering; when I push to my repo, how does tagging work? If I have one dockerfile that uses a 32-bit binary, can I push the image to the same tag that I pushed the 64-bit binary to? How do I know that my old image wasn't overwritten?

Answer (score -1):

You have to tag you image, by using the `docker tag` command :

`docker tag <id> <image_name>:<tag>`

Every time you build a new image for a specific architecture, tag it and then push it to your docker hub repository.

**Example**:

64bit:

`docker tag xxxx myImage:64bit`

32bit

`docker tag yyyy myImage:32bit`

And so on...

Comment: This is contrary to how it is on dockerhub though, if I pull `alpine:latest`, then docker will automatically select from multiple images, the one that matches my architecture. see here that there are multiple images under the same tag: https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine?tab=tags&page=1&ordering=last_updated

Comment: You asked, and here I quote "_I'm wondering; when I push to my repo, how does tagging work?_", hence my answer. Back to the question in this case,you may want to take a look a the multi-arch build, by using the `docker manifest` command. To make sure you're not ovewriting anything while testing, just add another tag to your image, so it won't be totally ovewritten, just the `latest`, but at least you have a backup